# How to compare two DEMs?

Tags: raster, dem, geotiff-tiff, srtm

I am new to GIS and I want to compare two DEM raster .tiff files, i.e. I want to compute differences between height values etc.

How can I determine if the two tiff files are comparable?

I have read that SRTM is measured relative to sea level, [here](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/faq.html). So is it measured relative "mean sea level"? Or is that equivalent?

The other tiles were given originally based on the height reference 'DE_DHHN2016_NH' with crs 'ETRS89_UTM32' and geoid 'DE_AdV_GCG2016_QGH', documentation is [here](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/dgm1_xyz/dgm1_meta.zip).

The SRTM tile dgalinfo gives me:

```
Driver: SRTMHGT/SRTMHGT File Format
Files: N50E007.hgt
Size is 3601, 3601
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (6.999861111111112,51.000138888888891)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   6.9998611,  51.0001389) (  6d59'59.50"E, 51d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  (   6.9998611,  49.9998611) (  6d59'59.50"E, 49d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right (   8.0001389,  51.0001389) (  8d 0' 0.50"E, 51d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right (   8.0001389,  49.9998611) (  8d 0' 0.50"E, 49d59'59.50"N)
Center      (   7.5000000,  50.5000000) (  7d30' 0.00"E, 50d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=3601x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-32768
  Unit Type: m
```

I merged the other tiles to get one large raster. Here are the details given by gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: bonn_dsmEPSG_4647.tif
Size is 14000, 18000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",32500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4647"]]
Origin = (32359999.500000000000000,5627999.500000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (32359999.500, 5627999.500) (  7d 0'49.80"E, 50d47'12.56"N)
Lower Left  (32359999.500, 5609999.500) (  7d 1'14.38"E, 50d37'30.16"N)
Upper Right (32373999.500, 5627999.500) (  7d12'44.43"E, 50d47'24.12"N)
Lower Right (32373999.500, 5609999.500) (  7d13' 6.55"E, 50d37'41.66"N)
Center      (32366999.500, 5618999.500) (  7d 6'58.80"E, 50d42'27.28"N)
Band 1 Block=14000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```